# How to extract part of a domain from a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex

If my domain is `31.example.appspot.com` (App Engine prepends a version number), I can retrieve the domain from the Request object like this:

```
String domain = request.getServerName();
// domain == 31.example.appspot.com
```

What I want is to extract everything except the version number so I end up with two values:

```
String fullDomain; // example.appspot.com
String appName;    // example
```

Since the domain could be anything from:

```
1.example.appspot.com
```

to:

```
31.example.appspot.com
```

**How do I extract the `fullDomain` and `appName` values in Java?**

Would a regex be appropriate here?

Answer (score 4):

If you are always sure of this pattern, then just find the first dot and start from there.

```
fullDomain = domain.subString(domain.indexOf('.'));
```

**UPDATE**: after James and Sean comments, here is the full correct code:

```
int dotIndex = domain.indexOf(".")+1;
fullDomain = domain.substring(dotIndex);
appName = domain.substring(dotIndex,domain.indexOf(".",dotIndex));
```

Comment: You may want to add how to get appName also, so save the indexOf value to an int, then use that for the two substring calls.

Comment: actually: `domain.indexOf('.') + 1`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method on java.lang.String.